# Should I define Pandas DataFrame column names as string variables?

Tags: python, pandas, pep8

I'm working with pandas DataFrames and I was wondering what the convention was for referring to column names. Should I define column names as string variables at the top of a cell? That way if I ever decide to change a column name I only need to change the variable assignment?

Looked through PEP 8 [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) but couldn't see any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is a fine one, but beware. If you have a column called `"foo"`, and define
`col = "foo"`, then, although you can refer to the column by `df.foo`, you *can not* refer to it as `df.col`, and have to use `df[col]`.